# Automated download script

Tags: linux, unix

I'd like to run a script that reads a list of URL's from a file and downloads each URL one at a time. The script reads one line from my url list and invokes the command

aria2c -D  &

completes 1st URL then goes to 2nd URL and so on till the end of the list. Help

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean that aria2c is the program that does the downloading or that you want the files downloading and then execute aria2c after getting each one?

Answer (score 3):

For things like this i use

```
wget -i file.ext
```

Edit: http://aria2.sourceforge.net/ is the website of aria2c. There are some nice examples like downloading all urls found in a file..

```
$ aria2c -i uris.txt
```

Before asking, consider doing a bit of research, a quick 'man aria2c' or 'aria2c --help' might give you the answer faster.

Answer (score 0):

To download from a script, use `wget`.

Answer (score 0):

```
while read line
do
    aria2c -s 5 "$line"
done < fileurllist
```